# What 1867 act of US congress entered this painting for the Southern District of New York? What did this act of congress actually do?

Tags: united-states, congress, specific-legislation, copyright

CNN's Abby Phillip's video [Where the fight for the Black vote really started | History Refocused](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIEShFFvYic) at about the 6 minute mark during a discussion of reconstruction, a work of art is shown during narration, called [Bateman's National Picture; Black-and-white reproduction of an illustration of an allegorical representation of Reconstruction, c.1867](https://64parishes.org/entry-image/batemans-national-picture) See also Smithsonian Museum of American History's [Reconstruction](https://americanhistory.si.edu/collections/search/object/nmah_324694).

The caption at the bottom of the engraving says:

> Entered according to Act of Congress in the year 1867 by Horatio Bateman, in the Clerks Office of the District Court of the U.S. for the S. District of N.Y.

**Question:** What 1867 act of US congress entered this painting for the Southern District of New York? What did this act of congress actually *do?*

Other links:

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Reconstruction_-_eng._by_J.L._Giles,_N.Y._;_printed_by_F(rancis)_Ratellier,_171_Broadway,_N.Y._LCCN2004665356.jpg (with a link to the largest size reproduction I can find)
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Reconstruction_LCCN2004665356.jpg
- https://www.loc.gov/pictures/item/2004665356/

---

[image] click for larger view

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There was no 1867 Act of Congress relating to this specific print. The Act referred to is actually an [1802 amendment to the Copyright Act of 1790](https://govtrackus.s3.amazonaws.com/legislink/pdf/stat/2/STATUTE-2-Pg171.pdf), section one of which provides the wording to be included in a map, chart, or book in order to claim copyright:

> *Be it enacted by the Senate and House of Representatives of the United States of America in Congress assembled*, That every person who
> shall, from and after the first day of January next, claim to be the
> author or proprietor of any maps, charts, book or books, and shall
> thereafter seek to obtain a copyright of the same [...] shall cause
> the following words to be impressed on the face thereof, viz: *"Entered
> according to act of Congress, the __ day of 18___ (here insert the
> date when the same was deposited in the office) by A. B. of the state
> of _____ (here insert the author's or proprietor's name and the state
> in which he resides.)*

Section two of the amendment applies the same rules to prints. The effect of the Act was to prescribe the rules by which an author or proprietor could claim copyright - this lasted for 14 years, renewable for an additional 14 years if the copyright holder was still alive.

In the [Copyright Act of 1831 (page 437)](https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/ll/llsl//llsl-c21/llsl-c21.pdf), the wording was amended to that included on this specific print; "*Entered
according to act of Congress, in the year ____ ,by A. B., in the clerk's
office of the district court of ______*". The date 1867 in the inscription therefore just refers to the year the work was copyrighted.

Comment: Interesting! So that’s basically a “long form” copyright mark and of no particular notability beyond that?

Comment: @uhoh yep, exactly - the option to just write 'Copyright' instead of the long-form was introduced by an 1874 amendment to the 1870 Copyright Act.

Comment: @uhoh you seem to have misread "according to" as meaning "by."

Comment: @phoog yes I think you are right, and I also assigned " in the year 1867" to "act of Congress" rather than to "entered". It seems I was parsing in my own private Idaho?

Comment: @uhoh once you interpret "according to" as "by," the misinterpretation of the year follows very naturally :-)